# Syntax error on token "void", record expected

Tags: java, классы, методы, map, void

```
package ua.com.filatova;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CollectionManipulations {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    Map<Integer, String>heshMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer,String>linkedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<Integer,String>treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
    
    public void testMap (Map<Integer,String>map) {
      
      map.put(39, "Bob");
      map.put(12, "Mike");
      map.put(78, "Tom");
      map.put(0, "Tim");
      map.put(1500, "Lewis");
      map.put(7, "Bob");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,String>entry):map.entrySet()){
      System.out.println(entry.getKey()+":"entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод не может быть в методе. Ваш `testMap` находится в методе `main`: так быть не должно. Либо вы неправильно прикрепили код. Вот так ваш код успешно скомпилируется:

```
package ua.com.filatova;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CollectionManipulations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, String> linkedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        testMap(hashMap);
        testMap(linkedMap);
        testMap(treeMap);
    }

    public static void testMap(Map<Integer, String> map) {
        map.put(39, "Bob");
        map.put(12, "Mike");
        map.put(78, "Tom");
        map.put(0, "Tim");
        map.put(1500, "Lewis");
        map.put(7, "Bob");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Помимо этого, в вашем коде было очень много синтаксических ошибок, из-за которых программа не компилировалась. Современные IDE показывают, что нужно для компиляции. К примеру если: `Expecting ';'`, то вам нужно поставить `;` в этой строке.